# Sup Inf Inequality

Tags: analysis, inequality, supremum-and-infimum

I try to solve the following problem:

Let $\varphi: D \to \mathbb{R}$ with $-\varphi(x) = \varphi(-x)$. Then $\underset{x \in D}{sup} \;(\varphi(x) - \varphi(\tilde{x}))\leq \underset{x\in D}{sup} \left(\varphi(x) - \underset{\tilde{x} \in D}{inf} \; \varphi(\tilde{x})\right)$. So my idea behind this inequality is that the difference only gets bigger if I subtract the smallest function value. This should be okay, I think.

I want to obtain the following inequality:
$\underset{x \in D}{sup} \;(\varphi(x) - \varphi(\tilde{x})) \leq \underset{x \in D}{sup} \; \underset{\tilde{x} \in D}{inf} \left(\varphi(x) - \varphi(\tilde{x})\right)$.

So my idea is to use the first inequality and move on with:
$\begin{align*}
\underset{x \in D}{sup} \;(\varphi(x) - \varphi(\tilde{x}))&\leq \underset{x\in D}{sup} \left(\varphi(x) - \underset{\tilde{x} \in D}{inf} \; \varphi(\tilde{x})\right)
&\leq \underset{x \in D}{sup} \; \underset{\tilde{x} \in D}{inf} \left(\varphi(x) - \varphi(\tilde{x})\right),
\end{align*}$

but I'm really not sure if this holds. I think it could be because of $-\varphi(x) = \varphi(-x)$. So basically my question is if $\varphi(x) - \underset{\tilde{x}\in D }{inf} \varphi(\tilde{x}) = \underset{\tilde{x} \in D}{inf} \left(\varphi(x) - \varphi(\tilde{x})\right)$ holds. Can someone please help me with figuring this out?

Comment: If $\tilde{x}$ does not depend on $x$ then this is trivial from the fact that $\varphi(\tilde{x})\geq\inf_{\xi}\varphi(\xi)$ for any $\tilde{x}$

Comment: Yes, but this is just the first step, I think. But does it additionally hold that $\varphi(x) - \underset{\tilde{x}}{inf} \varphi(\tilde{x}) = \underset{\tilde{x}}{inf} (\varphi(x)-\varphi(\tilde{x}))$?

Comment: Yes, since $x$ and $\tilde{x}$ do not depend on each other. This is just because $\varphi(x)$ is just a constant when you consider $\tilde{x}$

Comment: That was just what I thought, but I think I can construct a counter example: If $\varphi(x) = x$ with $D = [2,5]$. Then: $\varphi(x) - \underset{\tilde{x} \in [2,5]}{inf} \varphi(\tilde{x}) = x - 2 \geq x- 5 = \underset{\tilde{x} \in [2,5]}{inf} \left(\varphi(x) - \varphi(\tilde{x})\right)$ for $x \in [2,5]$, which is a contradiction to the inequality. Or did I understand something in the wrong way?

Comment: Ah wait nevermind, I missed the minus sign for some reason. So yeah it does not hold. In general $-\inf_x f(x)=\sup_x \bigl(-f(x)\bigr)$

Comment: Can I fix this somehow since $-\varphi(x) = \varphi(-x)$?

Comment: Doubt it. Best I can see is that $-\inf_{\tilde{x}}\varphi(\tilde{x})=-\inf_{\tilde{x}}\bigl(-\varphi(-\tilde{x})\bigr)=\sup_{\tilde{x}}\varphi(-\tilde{x})$

Answer (score 1):

The equality

$$\inf_{\tilde{x}\in D}\left(\varphi(x)-\varphi(\tilde{x})\right)\color{red}=\varphi(x)-\inf_{\tilde{x}\in D}\varphi(\tilde{x})$$

does **not** hold for all such $\varphi$. As a counterexample, consider $\varphi=\sin:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$. Then

$$-\sin(x)=\sin(-x)$$

for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$, but

$$\inf_{\tilde{x}\in\mathbb{R}}\left(\sin(x)-\sin(\tilde{x})\right)=\sin(x)-1,$$

but

$$\sin(x)-\inf_{\tilde{x}\in\mathbb{R}}\sin(\tilde{x})=\sin(x)+1.$$